# NodeJS and Websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

Today is my first time using NodeJS, and Socket.io more particularly. I developed a website with a PHP framework and would like to add notification and chat features. I'm following the [tutorial](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) on the Socket.io website trying to adapt it to my needs, but I have a few questions.

- First, I see that they are creating an HTTP server. What I want is the website to keep working as usual, meaning HTTP requests to be handled the same way, but on top of that I would like a websocket to be created whenever a page is loaded. So instead of

  ```
  var http = require('http').Server(app);
  http.listen(3000, function(){ console.log('listening on *:3000'); });
  ```

could we create a websocket server and use the WS protocol instead? I've seen a few libraries online but I would like to know if there is a standard one or a better way to do it.

- The other thing is I can't find the right path to the server-side Socket.io script. Therefore the connection can't be established. From I saw online, it should look like *DOMAIN/socket.io:3000*. Now I'm getting lost since it's my first time using Node: where can I find this "socket.io" file on the server? In my project folder, all I see is a *node_modules* folder (which does include a *socket.io* folder but I'm not sure how to use it).

Please note that my script on the server runs without any errors, even though I haven't had a chance to establish a connection

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```

Here's the current code on the client side:

```
var socket = io('<?php echo base_url(); ?>:3000, {path: "/sockets/socket.io"}');
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `localhost:3000`?

Comment: To your first question, you need to have two separate ports, one for the normal website and one for the websocket server.

Comment: @AniSkywalker I know, and that's why I'm using port 3000, while the website is handled by PHP using the port 80.

Comment: @ExplosionPills where?

Comment: You do not want to be connecting to the `/sockets/socket.io`.  That path is reserved for the client-side socket.io.js file.  Unless you're trying to do something special with the path on the server (which you do not show code for), then you should not specify a path in the client-side `io()` call.  I'd also suggest you look at exactly what `<?php echo base_url(); ?>:3000` turns on to be to make sure it's what you expect and what your server is listening on.  You should just be connecting socket.io to `http://yourdomain.com:3000`, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS is a webserver. Unlike PHP, you can run multiple servers on different ports from one server. So this creates a webserver:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

http.get("/",(req,res)=>res.write("Hello World"));

http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And this is the socket:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('a user connected');
});
```

Note that Socket.io needs a webserver for their handshake,so an additional http server is neccessary. However, you dont need to use this server for serving pages, so you can do:

```
var io = require("socket.io")(8000);//creates a webserver on port 8000, no need to do more with the pure http server
io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('a user connected');
});
```

---

Unlike PHP you dont need to embed scripts, you can import them:

```
var so=require("socket.io");//works if socket.io is installed in modules
```

Comment: 1) If I leave the upper part, how do I specify which port to listen to? 2) Why do I have to use the http protocol and not the ws one?

Comment: @user1319182 the ws isnt supported by all browsers etc. So a http server is needed.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but then how do I solve my second issue with the 404 error?

Comment: @user1319182 i dont know. test if the server is running etc.also have a look at https://davidwalsh.name/websocket